# htaccess non-www redirect error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Here is my htaccess code,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

when I type "http://mysite.com/username" it works

but when I type "http://www.mysite.com/username"
it's redirecting to "http://mysite.com/profile.php?user=username"

how can I fix that?

Comment: Can you be more clear on the problem? What should http://www.mysite.com/username redirect to?

Comment: what I want is, when I type "http://www.mysite.com/username" redirect to "http://mysite.com/username" but it goes to "http://mysite.com/profile.php?user=username"

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, this will remove the "www" which I think is partly what you want.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I get the impression that this is tied in with GET variables aswell?

Comment: sorry, don't think I can help anymore then :(

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because the `.htaccess` in your `/`(DocumentRoot) is getting read again.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

Also,
no need to add

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
```

more than once. Remove the second entries.

Comment: @Rothzerg what did you do? did you use `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200` or the other solution I mentioned? you need to give details!

Comment: @Rothzerg what other rewrite rules do you have?

Comment: I dont have anthing else, just those 10 lines :/

Comment: @Rothzerg I just tested it. Doesn't happen here even with the `/` in front of `profile.php`. You need to give more details.

Comment: here is my latest htaccess file

Options +FollowSymLinks 
 
RewriteEngine On
 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sitename.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(mysite\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for your relpy anubhava but I just tried it, still doesn't work  :s

Comment: awww, it works very well

but when I type www.mysite.com/foo
it goes to http://mysite.com/profile.php?user=foo

Comment: That's weird, I made an edit can you pls try this. Also can you paste relevant access.log lines here if that doesn't work.

Comment: nope, still doesn't work,


115.**.**.** - - [13/Feb/2012:15:35:32 -0600] "GET /profile.php?user=emre HTTP/1.1" 200 4393 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7"

Comment: Why am I seeing `GET /profile.php?user=emre` in your access.log ? If you notice I am not using `R` flag in second rule hence your URL should remain `mysite.com/emre`. Please post all of the .htaccess you have in your question (not in comment). Also post previous few lines of access.log as well.